# Send Email from Platform Events

Tags: managed-package, platform-event, configuration

Is there a way that our customers can configure the User setting in PlatformEventsSubscriberConfig to specify a User in their production org?  If so, how?
See " The username of the user that the platform event..." at the link below.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.248.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm

If it is not possible, what is the Salesforce best practice to send emails via Platform events?

For background, we're trying to send emails from data in a Platform Event records, which is by default disallowed by SF.  This operation was previously handled by a batch job, but we are attempting to update it to a combination of Platform Events and @future methods. The problem is that we are unable to send email under the context of the Automated Process user.

A potential solution is to set the User via PlatformEventsSubscriberConfig. On my end, I am able to do this via Metadata in VS Code and deploy it to a Scratch Org. However, we're wondering how this would be done for our customers in the production org for themselves after installing the package.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for a subscriber to change the contextual user for a packaged Platform Event apex trigger based subscriber (at least I haven't found a way).

Consider assigning a relevant permission set, that grants email permissions, to the Automated Process user, along the lines of [this help article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000394596&type=1):

```
insert new PermissionSetAssignment(
        AssigneeId = [SELECT Id FROM User WHERE alias = 'autoproc'].Id,
        PermissionSetId = '<your Permission Set Id here>');
```

An alternative is to simply use a flow-based platform event subscriber; these run as the originally publishing contextual user, rather than the Automated Process user.

NB: I would recommend against adopting `@Future` methods, instead doing the processing directly in the Platform Event trigger based subscriber if possible. If you cannot (e.g. you need to be able to perform a callout), instead use `Queueable` implementations. This then allows you to use a transaction finalizer to recover from error scenarios (including governor limit issues).

In case it is of use, take a look at [this example solution](https://github.com/sirephil/sf-async-callout) to doing heavy lifting (including callouts) robustly and in a deterministic order, starting from an object trigger. You might also like to read [this article](https://www.apexhours.com/governor-friendly-asynchronous-processing-from-triggers/).

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was to update the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig user via a PATCH request to the tooling API.

`/services/data/v60.0/tooling/sobjects/PlatformEventSubscriberConfig/<ID>`

and pass in the desired user Id in the request body.

`{"UserId": "028J8000091KDIIIAQ"}`

After making this change, the Platform Event Subscription must be suspended and resumed for the change to take effect.

More information in the docs: [PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_platformeventsubscriberconfig.htm)

Comment: Be warned that using the tooling API and metadata API from managed apex will be very difficult to get through any security review. Do not try using the Session ID to do this; if you do, your app will be rejected and you will be told to rework it to use a Connected App and OAuth flows. It will be a huge effort and, I suspect, really not worth it just to spoof a user (which will also be something likely to cause you to fail security review).