# how to use PlatformEventSubscriberConfig in a managed package?

Tags: apex, platform-event, platformeventsubscriberconfig

I'm working on a managed package that has many installs. I'd like to configure a Platform Event trigger to run as a different User in each org that it is installed in. See: [Documentation about PlatformEventSubscriberConfig](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_trigger_config.htm) The result I want is that for Org1 the PE trigger should run as "Alice" and in Org2, the PE trigger should run as "Bob", etc. Those would be individual user accounts in each org.

But the [Components Available In Managed Package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pkg2_dev.meta/pkg2_dev/packaging_packageable_components.htm) documentation says that the "User" attribute of the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig is not editable by the subscriber. As an ISV, I don't know who the User should be at the time of packaging. Is there a way to use this feature for my scenario?

I'm thinking of generating the PlatformEventSubscriberConfig with a POST, but then it would not be in the same namespace as the managed package, the PE trigger. Would that be successful?

Comment: Does [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416806/send-email-from-platform-events) answer your question? Trying to do this from managed package code and using the metadata API will be a hard slog. What is the reason you need this? Could you simply have it run as the publishing contextual user? If so, switch to a flow-based platform event subscriber.

Comment: I would doubt it. I would also say that impersonating another user in this way is unlikely to pass a security review, while running as either the contextual user or the Automated Process user will.

Comment: The names 'Alice and Bob' above are not good examples; the automated process user is very appealing for this and represents the need. But it has its own security inconveniences.

Comment: Your managed package can assign perm sets to the automated process user via your "post install script" which may remove many of the inconveniences.

Comment: Yes, that might get us close enough to where we want to be.