# Manage Platform Event Trigger Subscriptions From Apex

Tags: trigger, platform-event

Is there a way to manage platform events trigger subscriptions programmatically? Specifically, I'd like to be able suspend and resume a trigger subscription using Apex code.

I am aware of how to  [change it from the UI](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_platform_events_manage_subscribers.htm&release=228&type=5), but I would like to write an Apex method that can do this automatically, rather than having do to the manual step.

Comment: I cannot see any metadata that would allow you to control this. I wondered if this was changing the Active status on a Platform Event Apex trigger based subscriber, but it does not appear to (having had a quick play). I think this must be through some org metadata that is not exposed in the metadata API (nor in the Tooling API either).

Comment: AFAIK there's no programmatic way to do this. What is your ultimate goal here? (See [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Likely relates to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/416806/send-email-from-platform-events).

Comment: The goal was to try to update PlatformEventSubscriberConfig via the Tooling API, and then suspend and resume the Subscription so the change takes effect. It can, of course, be done manually, but was just trying to see if it could be done programmatically.